# HttpservletRequest path info is not getting set properly

Tags: java, servlets

I set the Path INFO for my HttpservletRequest as below.

```
request.setAttribute("javax.servlet.include.path_info", pathInfo);
```

After this statement i tried to get the pathinfo , but that is returning null.

```
String info = request.getPathInfo();
```

info is `null` here.

Am I setting the path correctly?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work that way. HttpServletRequest objects are read-only, apart from the attributes. What you can do though is replace the request object with a wrapped one that returns the Path info you want. Usually you would do that in a [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) and wrap the request in a [`HttpServletRequestWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html).

Comment: Thanks Sean..Actually i want to modify the path info of a received request. After modifying the path info of the request i have to call an actionservlet.post operation. Is there any example resource available for modifying request path info.

Comment: @user3147325 that's exactly ths use case for a httpservlerwrapper. Overwrite the gatPathInfo method in the wrapper to return the pathinfo you need.

Answer (score 1):

The second part is wrong. If you set an attribute to the servlet request, you can get it only via the `getAttribute` method.

so if you set the value using:

`request.setAttribute("javax.servlet.include.path_info", pathInfo);`

The you'd get that value back using:

`request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.include.path_info");`

Now `request.getPathInfo()` gives the extra path information after the URI. In your case it would be null, because there would be nothing after the URI:

**E.G - if you have a url = http://someHost.com/servletName?id=1234&name=fred**

`request.getPathInfo()` would return **id=1234*name=fred**

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Actually i wannt to modify an existing request objects path info and parameters. After modification i want to use this request in calling dopost of an actionservlet. Is there any way(good/bad) of modifying the request object. I have seen HttpServletRequestWrapper examples, little confused .Can you point me to a proper example which suits my requirement

Comment: Why would you want to do that way? Anyway you can't modify the pathInfo of a servlet. It's readonly. I'd create a  pathInfo as a requestAttribute and pass it to the servlet. And in that servlet I'll get it and use it for doPosting. Does that make sense. If not I didn't understand your question clearly.